# Can Ratio test be true for nonpositive sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We know from Ratio test of sequence that,

> For a sequence $\{u_n\}$ of positive real numbers with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=l$ (i) $0\le l<1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=0$ and (ii) $l>1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\infty.$

Can the same be concluded for any real sequence instead of positive real sequence?

Comment: What are you asking for? All the terms non-positive, or any real sequence?

Comment: any real sequence

Comment: Is it true that if the limit you mention is positive, then all the u_n terms must eventually have the same sign?  It seems like that's true.

Comment: @Jave Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_{n + 1} / u_n = \ell > 0$ then the sequence $\{u_n\}$ eventually has constant sign - if not, there would be infinitely many sign changes and the set of indices with negative ratio would be infinite. This implies $\ell \le 0$, which is not the case.

---

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_{n + 1} / u_n = 0$, then it is very easy to argue that $u_n \to 0$.

So in that sense, you can still draw a lot of conclusions without the positivity assumption. Alternatively, you could just apply the test to the sequence $\{|u_n|\}_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Ratio test is only valid for definitively positive (or negative) sequences, i.e. sequences for which exists $n^*$ such that the sequences doesn’t change sign for $n>n^*$

Comment: what about not definitely positive/negative sequence? any counterexample?

Comment: My intuition is that the ratio test stated by Jave would hold for any sequence of real numbers, because my intuition is that if the ratio limit is 0, then the limit of u_n is 0, and if the ratio limit is positive, then your "doesn't change sign for n > n*" condition holds.

Comment: EG $a_n = 0$ for n even $a_n = \frac1n$ otherwise